# $apply in setTimeout

Tags: angularjs, apply, ng-switch

I konw that `$apply` used to connect the Javascript context and the AngularJS context.

A simple example is below:

template:

```
<div>{{someVal}}</div>
```

javascript in controller:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    scope.$apply(function(){scope.someVal = 123});
}, 1000);
```

We need use `$apply` in above situation.

First Qustion:

If I modify javascript above to:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    scope.someVal = 123;
}, 1000);

scope.$watch('someVal', function(val) {
    console.info(someVal);
});
```

No console about someVal modified to 123... Why? Can't we watch expression modified in timeout callback?

Second Question:

If we use ngSwitch directive like below:

```
<div ng-switch on="sub">
    <div ng-switch-when="a">
//state a
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="b">
//state b
    </div>
</div>
```

When I modify the `sub` in controller:

```
scope.sub = 'a';
setTimeout(function() {
    scope.sub = 'b';
}, 1000);
```

No need to use `$apply`!!!! Why?

I found that ngSwitch directive use `$watch` to monitor `on` attribute value. Why ngSwitch can watch scope attribute modified in timeout callback?????

Pls tell me the reason about the 2 qustions above.

Comment: The second question is solved! The $apply for someVal is triggered in other $apply, like http://jsfiddle.net/stefanqi/Jvak8/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [AngularJs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope) documentation

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events, setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into the angular framework we need to perform proper scope life cycle of exception handling, executing watches.

[window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) is a JavaScript function, so whatever you use `setTimeout` **you must use $apply()** to update the model.

Your second example **wouldn't work without `$apply()`**, I've made a <kbd>[**demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rn4gFiOheAj6wliITTy8?p=preview)</kbd> to clarify the `$watch` and `$apply` issue. Please check it.

Comment: Sorry, I can not access your demo.

Comment: You are right! I found that the $apply for someVal is triggered in other $apply... I make a fiddle about what I came across: http://jsfiddle.net/stefanqi/Jvak8/. Anyway, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$timeout](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24timeout) that is a wrapper for window.setTimeout and also this way you wont need to use $apply on the callback:

> $timeout(function() {
>       scope.someVal = 123; }, 1000);

When you run code that is outside Angular, you'll need a way to let the Angular and the watchers of that value, to know that it has changed. Thats what [$apply](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24apply) is for, it will allow watch listeners to fire

About you second question, of **why** the scope is updating without a $apply, you should be firing indirectly somehow a $apply/$digest. To give you a more specific answer, a Plunker will be necessary to check what else in going on on your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Angularjs [$timeout service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24timeout) instead of setTimeout and you will not require $apply. Same thing is if you are using a jquery http call, use the angular http service to avoid using $apply.